# jquery: how set in object another one object with key like - this.id?

Tags: jquery

if i write:

```
function myindex(name){
var cut_point = name.lastIndexOf('_')+1;
return name.substring(cut_point);
}
...
var ind = myindex(some_id);    
var data_users = {};
var $data_users = $(data_users);
$data_users.prop('user_'+ind,{this.id:$(this).val()});
```

were this.id = 'login'( from <\input type="text" id="login"> value="<\?=$user->Login ?>"/>) it will be wrong. but i neeed:

> data_users = {
>                  user_3: {
>                          login: Rocsana
>                        }
>                }

for example, if I write so:

```
$data_users.prop(this.id,$(this).val());
```

then key setting correct:

> data_users = {login: "Rocsana"}

but i need this in object 'user_3'. please help.

p.s. I need to track every change in fields linked to the user, adding them (changes) in the object and then the changes I am sending ajax in php, using json. for example

> data_users {user_3 {login: Rocsana, role: Admin, e-mail:
>   test@test.com}, user_2 {...}}

keys "login", "role", ... identical to the fields of the table "Users". it's easier to make a database query "UPDATE". just parse the object and received the names of the fields that need to update.

Comment: what are you trying to get the ID of? nothing in your sample code is dealing with any DOM elements.

Comment: u should expalin your problem better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what your asking, you dont need to use JQuery for the creation and addition of the your issue.  Using native JS would be easier anyway.  Example below...

```
// Make the data_users object
var data_users = {};

// Creates the property "test" on the data_users object
// Add it this way and you can reference it like "data_users.test"
data_users['test'] = {};


// Add a key/value pair (object) to data_users.test
    // You can put this  below line in a $.each or for loop and iterate through
    // your jquery elements and add them all the the data_users.test object this way.
data_users.test[this.id] = $(this).val();
/*
    Example:   data_users.test["SOMEID"] = "SOMEVALUE";
    Reference: data_users.test.SOMEID would return the string "SOMEVALUE"
*/
```

Comment: Brand, many thanks. I was asked to explain more clearly what I want (erimerturk). and can already see that I can not take your advice because like so:
data_users.user_ + ind [this.id] = $ (this). val ();
would be a mistake to write ...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with help Brand:) On his example i now simply invest js-object in js-object:

```
var data_users = {};
...
var specific_users = {};
specific_users[this.id] = $(this).val();
(data_users['user_'+myindex(this.id)]==undefined) ? data_users['user_'+myindex(this.id)] = specific_data_user : $.extend(data_users['user_'+myindex(this.id)], specific_data_user);
```

but if anyone knows a more elegant solution to jQuery would be highly appreciated if you tell me:) ...